# For loop with multiplication step in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, syntax, for-loop, octave

Is there any way to use a for-loop in MATLAB with a custom step? What I want to do is iterate over all powers of 2 lesser than a given number. The equivalent loop in C++ (for example) would be:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 65; i *= 2)
```

*Note 1:* This is the kind of iteration that best fits for-loops, so I'd like to not use while-loops.
*Note 2:* I'm actually using Octave, not MATLAB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you want something along the lines of

```
for i=2.^[1:6]
   disp(i)
end
```

Except you will need to figure out the range of exponents.  This uses the fact that since
`a_(i+1) = a_i*2` this can be rewritten as `a_i = 2^i`.

Otherwise you could do something like the following

```
i=1;
while i<65
   i=i*2;
   disp(i);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over any vector, so you can use vector operations to create your vector of values before you start your loop. A loop over the first 100 square numbers, for example, could be written like so:

```
values_to_iterate = [1:100].^2;
for i = values_to_iterate
   i
end
```

Or you could loop over each *position* in the vector `values_to_iterate` (this gives the same result, but has the benefit that `i` keeps track of how many iterations you have done - this is useful if you are writing a result from each loop sequentially to an output vector):

```
values_to_iterate = [1:100].^2;
for i = 1:length(values_to_iterate)
   values_to_iterate(i)
   results_vector(i) = some_function( values_to_iterate(i) );
end
```

More concisely, you can write the first example as simply:

```
for i = [1:100].^2
   i
end
```

Unlike in C, there doesn't have to be a 'rule' to get from one value to the next. 
The vector iterated over can be completely arbitrary:

```
for i = [10, -1000, 23.3, 5, inf]
     i
end
```